# Java - Optimize finding a string in a list

Tags: java, optimization

I have an ArrayList of objects where each object contains a string 'word' and a date. I need to check to see if the date has passed for a list of 500 words.  The ArrayList could contain up to a million words and dates.  The dates I store as integers, so the problem I have is attempting to find the word I am looking for in the ArrayList.

Is there a way to make this faster?  In python I have a dict and mWords['foo'] is a simple lookup without looping through the whole 1 million items in the mWords array.  Is there something like this in java?

```
    for (int i = 0;  i < mWords.size();  i++) {
        if ( word == mWords.get(i).word ) {
           return mWords.get(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the words are unique then use HashMap. I mean, {"a", 1}, {"b", 2}

```
Map<String, Integer> wordsAndDates = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
wordsAndDates.put("a", 1);
wordsAndDates.put("b", 2);
```

and  `wordsAndDates.get("a") return 1`

If not you shouldn't use HashMap because it overrides previous value. I mean

```
wordsAndDates.put("a", 1);
wordsAndDates.put("b", 2);
wordsAndDates.put("a", 3);
```

and `wordsAndDates.get("a") return 3`

In such case you can use [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and search in it

Comment: Thanks guys! And thanks for the warning as it explains to me how the HashMap works.

Comment: you are welcome. it rejoices me that you learn something new today

Answer (score 1):

If you're not stuck with an `ArrayList` you should use some kind of hash based data structure.  In this case it seems like a [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) should fit nicely (it's pretty close to python's `dict`). This will give you an O(1) lookup time (compared to your current method of linear search).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) in Java

```
Map<String,Integer> mWords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
mWords.put ("foo", 112345);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [`Collections.binarySearch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) (NB: the list must be sorted) if ou are stuck with the `ArrayList`